# Запуск java-кода

Tags: java, intellij-idea, проект

Есть небольшая проблемка с программой IntelliJ IDEA - не могу выполнить java-код. Сделал как надо - во вкладке Bulid рядом сделал билд проекта, а кнопка Run тупо неактивна. На ютубе у всех все работает, а у меня непонятно в чем проблема. Помогите, пожалуйста, кто может!

[image: неактивные кнопка Run]

Comment: Кнопка Run ниже запускает окно "Edit Configurations", но не сам код

Comment: Кнопка неактивна в только что созданом проекте?

Answer (score 1):

1. Зайдите в Edit Configurations...
2. Нажмите + и выберите Application
3. В правой части введите имя конфигурации в Name, нажмите кнопочку
   [...] в той строке где Main class и выберите свой класс, содержащий
   функцию main
4. Жмём ОК
5. Запускаем

Comment: У меня почему-то в окошке, что открывается при нажатии на [...], класса не появляется, в поиске забивал, но тоже не находит.

Comment: Когда жмёте [...] там две закладки, нажмите вторую "Project" и явно выберите свой класс из проекта

Comment: Еще есть вариант, в самом проекте слева нажать правой кнопкой на этом файле с классом и там выбрать "Run 'Main'" (вместо Main имя выбранного файла)

Comment: на некоторое время оставил это, сейчас опять вернулся и все равно не нахожу этот класс во вкладке project (там вообще файлы вместо классов), а при втором варианте нет этой кнопки run main. Я не знаю зачем нельзя было сделать простую отладку, усложнили все зачем-то :/

Comment: @AidenProgrammer может у вас метод main неверно написан?